# Wich one do you think is a better solution for the product card of a grocery app

Tags: usability, gui-design

Which of the options do you think to have better usability for the product cards for a grocery app (Shoppers)
[image]

The problem: I need to give to shoppers a better visualization of the basic products information in a smooth way for them don't get confused y make their process more easy and fast

Solution: I think is a lot of information for a card so I tried to organize the information in a way that I considered clear and give a better reading

so in A we have in the top left the product name, in the top right the location of the product in-store and in the center of the cards the picture, the order quantity and other information that help to picker the product in a better way like reference, price, and barcode

At the bottom of the card, I have a client comment if the client sends one

In B we had the same information but the difference is that I display the order quantity at the same level that the product name and the location is now in the center

Leave me to know what you think! Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know is to do A/B testing

I personally prefer A

B would be better if you could somehow distinguish the `3x` from the Item Name with a more distinct styling or color.

Right now the quantity of the item is more obvious to me in design A.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why is the location in the store important for an online experience?
2. You have the product count but I don’t see an option to increase or decrease this value
3. Why is the barcode number needed on what I’m assuming is the quick/list view of products?
4. Each of these versions, including the original, have positive qualities but none of them currently achieve the right hierarchy

Comment: What do you mean with "right hierarchy"?

Comment: Location is really helpful *if* the app is used by people *in the store* to find products. I do that frequently with Home Depot, for example. It actually bothers me if a web site shows in-store inventory level but doesn't clearly show location.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with A but with the following recommendations:

- Increase the colour contrast in the message to make it stand out (e.g. black font)
- Move the quantity to the right side of the panel maybe with a grey background as in the original

Last but not least, as mentioned, try to only include the necessary information that the user needs to complete the order (e.g. Location, barcode, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If I`d like to shop something online, the first Information thats important for me is WHAT. So I would scale the main productname up.

The second information is probably either how much it costs (depends on how much of the current month is already over :) and how much product I would buy.

I am not interested in data like barcodes or locations (that one could be an information to use as a filter for the tiles if it is really relevant to the users goals)

Overall great attempts. Try to use font sizes that differentiate more and try to use not to many. For example use a bold headline with the name of the product. Then a smaller copytext for metadata in the middle of the tile and a larger maybe thinner typeface for the price.
I hope this helps. Good luck!